# mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header error after change server Plex to Cpanel

Tags: php, email, header

i am sending email with attached pdf file. when i am using plex panel below code is working fine now i updated with Cpanel this script could not work. above is code of email .please help me what to do .

i am sending email with attached pdf file. when i am using plex panel below code is working fine now i updated with Cpanel this script could not work. above is code of email .please help me what to do .

```
$to = $email.",billing@hotelsinkonkan.in"; 
$from = "billing@hotelsinkonkan.in"; 
$subject ="Instant e-Bill from www.hotelsinkonkan.in for ".$hotel_name; 


$message ="<html><head></head><body style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt; line-height:18px; color:#403437;'>";

$message .="Dear ".$contact.",<br/><br/>";

$message.="<p style='font-size:15px; color:#215868' >Thank you for being our Valued Customer and for using Instant e-Bill service.!</p>";

$message.="We are pleased to present your e-Bill for Advertise on www.hotelsinkonkan.in dated <strong>".date("d-m-y")."</strong> for the period ".$st_date1.' To '.$ed_date1."<br/>";

$message.="<p style='font-size:15px; color:#215868'>We value your relationship with us and assure you our best services at all times.</p>";

$message .="Thanks And Regards<br/>
Billing Hotels In Konkan<br/>
(Active Bit Technologies)<br/>";

$message.="<img style='margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;' src='http://hotelsinkonkan.in/admin/images/logo_mail.jpg'/><br/>";

$message .="Address - Dhayari Industrial Estate,<br/>
Near Pari Automation, Starling<br/>
Nisarga Phase ||, Dhayari<br/><br/>";

$message .="<p style='color:#292727'>Phone no : +91 020 - 32326630</p>";

$message .="<p>Website   : www.hotelsinkonkan.in<br/>";
$message .="Email : billing@hotelsinkonkan.in</p>";

$message .="Click Here to Download Hotels in Konkan <a href='http://slideme.org/application/hotelsinkokan'>Apps on Your Mobile</a><br/>"; 

$message.="<img style='margin:10px 0px 6px 0px;' src='http://hotelsinkonkan.in/admin/images/mail.jpg'/><br/>";

$message.="MPORTANT NOTICE:<br/>
Internet communications cannot be guaranteed to be timely, secure, error or virus-free. The sender, does not accept liability for any errors or omissions. Active Bit Technologies does not accept liability of mishandling of email account. The information in this email (and any attachments) is confidential. If you are not the intended recipient, you must not use or disseminate this information. If you have received this email in error, please immediately revert to support@activebittechnologies.com  and permanently delete the original and any copies or printouts thereof. Although this email and any attachments are believed to be free of any virus or other defect that might affect any computer system into which it is received and opened, it is the responsibility of the recipient to ensure that it is virus free and no responsibility is accepted by Active Bit Technologies. or their subsidiaries or affiliates either jointly or severally, for any loss or damage arising in any way from its use.";

$message .="</body></html>";

 echo $message;
$separator = md5(time());

$eol = PHP_EOL;

$filename =$pdf_name.".pdf";

$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));



$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;



$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;


$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
$headers .= "--".$separator."--";


mail($to, $subject, "", $headers);
```

Comment: Try using `"\n"` instead of `PHP_EOL`

Comment: Yet not working